# Is it possible to transfer light from edge to edge of transparent material?

Tags: visible-light

I don't know much about physics but i believe that this is the place to ask my question.

I'm using 3 monitor setup like this:

[image: setup]

the plastic bezels [ [image: bezels] ] are extremely annoying.

in order to make them disappear i thought about this solution:

Attaching a `glass` / `plexiglass` / `other transparent material` block equals to the size of the screen with large depth to each monitor so that it transfers the light from the monitor to the other side of the block

[image: block vs monitor]

---

final result:

[image: setup]

## And my Questions...

- Is it possible to transfer light from edge to edge of transparent material? (as described in images)
- if possible, which material should i use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is,  yes,sort of.  What you're missing is that once light leaves a point (pixel) on the monitor's surface, it radiates in all directions, which is why you can see the image wherever you're sitting.  The blocks of plastic you envision will not change this, so you'll find yourself just looking through them at offset images, rather as though they were prisms.

What you need is called a "light pipe."  This is made out of bundles of closely-spaced optical fibers, each of which constrains the light from a given pixel from radiating in other directions. Each pixel's output is forced to travel along one or a few fibers. Then, at the far side of the block, the light is freed to the air. The full image is reproduced at this far side.   I do have to warn you that obtaining large sheets of light pipe is unlikely to be easy or cheap.

Comment: An example in natural stone: [ulexite](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/ulexite/ulexite7.jpg). Pretty nice to see.

Comment: @Davidmh  that's awesome!  Thanks for the link.  Guess I should have taken a geology course :-)

Comment: @Carl Just hang around in stores that sell rocks and minerals; I learned about this one in such a place.  There are often explanatory cards that seem happy to tell you what is awesome about some stone (though that thing is often about auras and not images).

Answer (score 3):

You can also Google "edgeless computer monitor".   Three new monitors is likely to be cheaper than a fiber bundle!

Comment: And possibly, if the contacts on the LCD display aren't on the edge in your current monitors, you might just be able to remove the edges and slide them together.

Answer (score 1):

I think, it would not be possible to hide those plastic bezels with your arrangement. Light from the external sources will be hitting those plastic bezels, then passing through the glass towards your eye. Then you will see the bezels.

---

*Reference needed from reliable sources.*

Comment: Naah, if that's all it took you could cover the bezels with some heavily absorbing black material